# Word form for Number in Ancient Obscure Language

Tags: historical-linguistics, computational-linguistics, numbers, numerals

The problem gives 7 numbers and 7 **unmatched** word forms in **random order**.  `15, 1,16,2,10,11,14` and `aina-bumfit, para-dig,bumfit,aina-dig,aina,dig,peina` The question is to figure out the number *peina-bumfit* represents. If it makes a different, the problem states that this counting was used to count sheep in Millom,Cumbria in Northern England.

> 

I assumed that when dashes were involved then it meant there were two digits. That would mean there are a minimum of 4 single-digit numbers since there are 4 un-dashed phrases. So the base has to be greater than 11 since it's 1,2,10,11... in order. But you have "para" and "aina"(assuming powers increase from right to left) and "bumfit and "dig"(is powers increase left to right). Then one of the leading digits would be at minimum 1 and the other at minimum 2. But then the value represented by the 2 digit would need to be at least (11 + 1)*2 =  24, which is greater than any of the listed numbers

> 

Could someone please help me with this? Thank you. If there is anything wrong with this question please tell me, this is my first question on Linguistics Stack Exchange.

Comment: An interesting homework question! You have a false assumption in your thinking, though: the base doesn’t necessarily have to be bigger than 11 – it could be base-5, for example, with simplex terms for 5, 10, 15 and 20, similar to how Welsh works. (You can easily Google the answer, but it’s more fun to work it out yourself. I will let you know, though, that Welsh is a hint here – if you know anything about Celtic languages, that will help you recognise some of the sheep-counting numbers.)

Comment: I went to check my answer on https://omniglot.com/language/numbers/celtic2.htm, and if the list there is correct, the numerals  you have been given don’t include 14. The correct number, 13, makes a slightly different solution less likely.

Comment: Perhaps the website where I found the problem had a typo. Thank you

Comment: My mistake was in assuming that the words followed a base system, where aina-peina would mean 1(base) + 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is already an accepted answer, I will give some more clues on how to decode this kind of riddle.

**Decoding without resorting to linguistic background information**

There are single morphemes (aina, bumfit, dig, paina, and para) and compounds. There are several possibilities in decoding the compounds:

- small + big (like in English *four-teen*)
- big + small (like in English *twenty-one*)
- times (like in French *quatre-vingt* "80", or English *four-ty* "40")
- -small + big (like in Latin *un-de-viginti* "19")

Since the *aina* occurs three times (once single, two times as prefix) we can guess that *aina* means "one", and that we have the small+big pattern. Since both 2 and 12 are in the number set, we indentify *paina-dig* as "12", solving two more words. Next we can see  that *bumfit* and *aina-bumfit* are 15 and 16 respectively, leaving *para-dig* for "14" (in the formulation of the riddle as given by the original post).

**Using linguistic background information**

Given that the numbers come from a part of England, their linguistic provenance is restricted to Germanic (including Anglo-Saxon and Nordic), Celtic (including dead Celtic languages like Brythonic and living ones like Welsh), and Romance (Norman French). Knowing the numbers in those languages quickly identifies *aina* as "one", *dig* as "ten", and *bumfit* as "something with five, either fifteen or fifty" and the given set of possible solutions narrows it down to "fifteen". *paina* and *para* are more distorted but can now be assigned using the other clues of the riddle.

P.S. A friend of mine (German native speaker) used to count dice steps in a board game (German orthographic transcription) *ein, pei, dei, fie, fum*

EDIT: The numbers used in the problem are known under the name *sheep-counting numbers* and there is a [Wikipedia article titled Yan tan tethera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yan_tan_tethera) about them.

Comment: +1 for actually showing the process! However, with the question as given and using no background info, I think another solution would assign 15 to *dig* and 10 to *bumfit*, taking *para* as 'one before' so that *para-dig* becomes 15-1=14. Then *peina-bumfit* would be 12. But as I wrote [in another comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/word-form-for-number-in-ancient-obscure-language#comment102279_44739), I'm not sure the question has it right; I think 14 should be replaced by 13. This makes the "-small + big" pattern, as you call it, less likely.

Answer (score 3):

Peina-bumfit is 17 - These are all corruptions of older Brythonic languages once spoken throughout England.

Peina is "2", Bumfit is "15", so essentially, '15 and 2'.

The older Celtic counting/numbers are not as in other European languages. They are vigesimal systems (based on 20)

In Welsh, for example, dau ar bymtheg ar ddeugain is 57 (two upon fifteen upon twoscore). 30 is "two 15s". It's a very different way of looking at numbers and counting!

Comment: In asking the bingleduck about this, I was led to [Yan tan tethera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yan_tan_tethera) at Wikipedia, and there are some additional links at [Sheep-scoring numbers at Omniglot](https://omniglot.com/language/numbers/celtic2.htm)